# Error in configure file

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, configure

I try to compile an old program which has these lines in the configure file:

```
4143 if ac_fn_c_try_compile "$LINENO"; then :
4144  ac_cv_prog_hostcc_works=1  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
4145 $as_echo "yes" >&6; }
     else
      as_fn_error $? "installation or configuration problem: host compiler $HOST_CC cannot create
      executables." "$LINENO" 5
     fi
```

This results in the following error:

```
./configure: line 4145: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./configure: line 4145: `$as_echo "yes" >&6; }'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: which language/compiler?

Comment: This is GCC on a SUSE Linux system.

Comment: Did you check the error line?

Comment: I am not really familiar with configure scripts and do not understand the error message.

When I comment out the bracket it runs but I doubt it does what it shall do:
4144  ac_cv_prog_hostcc_works=1  #{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
4145 #$as_echo "yes" >&6; }

Comment: You lack a space at the beginning of line `4145`, not sure if configure script are indentation sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there was a semicolon missing:

```
4144  ac_cv_prog_hostcc_works=1;  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
```